# How to monitor elasticsearch with Prometheus data source in Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, prometheus

I'm the beginner in Prometheus and Grafana.

I have created new dashboards in Grafana to monitor basic metrics of the server using Prometheus and Grafana.
in the same way needs to monitor elastic search in the servers.

I have followed the below steps :

I m not sure whether the below is the right approach.

I have tried below format for node_exporter process which results in success. that's y tried the below for elasticsearch exporters

in the Elastic search server(which is going to be monitored)

```
wget https://github.com/justwatchcom/elasticsearch_exporter/releases/download/v1.0.2rc1/elasticsearch_exporter-1.0.2rc1.darwin-386.tar.gz
tar -xf elasticsearch_exporter-1.0.2rc1.darwin-386.tar.gz 
cd elasticsearch_exporter-1.0.2rc1.darwin-386
 ./elasticsearch_exporter
```

while executing the last step i get the below error.

```
-bash: ./elasticsearch_exporter: cannot execute binary file
```

once this is done, how can i get the dashboards in Grafana for elasticsearch

Comment: just a comment, you get it the same way as you did it with the node_exporter. The prometheus server pickup up or scrapes the metrics from the elasticsearch exporter, puts the data in its database and then you can create the visualization for those metrics with grafana. That in generals works for any exporter that you might encounter...(I can show you the details if you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -bash: ./elasticsearch_exporter: cannot execute binary file

Typically the cause of this error is running an executable on the wrong architecture.

Double check the Elasticsearch binary you downloaded. You'll need to download the appropriate binary for your machine.